# The LINQ expression cannot be translated on Grouping

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, asp.net-core

I have LINQ expression to take top 15 most frequently used answers

Here is expression

```
 var latestAnswers = await _dbContext.TextAnswers.Include(x => x.CompanySurvey).ThenInclude(x => x.Survey)
        .Where(x => x.CompanySurvey.Survey.FiscalYear == 2022)
        .GroupBy(x => x.Answer)
        .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())
        .Take(15)
        .ToListAsync();
```

But I get this error

> The LINQ expression 'DbSet() .Include(x => x.CompanySurvey) .ThenInclude(x => x.Survey) .Where(x => x.CompanySurvey.Survey.FiscalYear == (int?)2022) .GroupBy(x => x.Answer) .OrderByDescending(g => g .AsQueryable() .Count()) .Take(__p_0)' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I can't understood why it cant be translated.

How I can fix this?

Comment: EF Core which version? Do not forget to specify. EF Core 6 has support for such query.

Comment: As I see project using Z.EntityFramework.Plus.EfCore package -  6.13.7 @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: Z project is not EF Core, it is just extension.

Comment: So EFCore 6.0.0 is using at project @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: Have you tried to remove `Includes`? Or you need related data at the end?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EF Core 6 has to support such queries, but looks like full implementation support is moved to EF Core 7

After conversation looks like it is not needed to get grouped records from database, but just grouping key and Count

```cs
var latestAnswers = await _dbContext.TextAnswers
    .Where(x => x.CompanySurvey.Survey.FiscalYear == 2022)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Answer)
    .Select(g => new { Answer = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
    .Take(15)
    .ToListAsync();
```

Answer (score 0):

I rewrite my code like this

```
 var latestAnswersQuery = await _dbContext.TextAnswers
        .Include(x => x.CompanySurvey).ThenInclude(x => x.Survey)
        .Where(x => x.CompanySurvey.Survey.FiscalYear == 2022)
        .ToListAsync();

    var latestAnswers = latestAnswersQuery.GroupBy(x => x.Answer).OrderByDescending(g => g.Count()).Take(15);
    return latestAnswers;
```

And now everything great

Comment: It is bad, because you have loaded not needed data into the memory.

Comment: Okay, so how I can do it better? @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: Preparing answer. Two questions. 1) Do you need Includes (related data loaded) 2) Why your query returns `IGrouping`? it is requrement?

Comment: 1) Yes, I need, cause `FiscalYear`, that  is in related table
2) It's because I need to Group all answers by `Answer` field and return Count of `Answer` fields and `Answer` value @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: If you use `FiscalYear` only for filter, you do not need `Include`

Comment: Your second answer tells me that you need only `.Select(g => new { g.Answer, g.Count() })` - it is not `IGrouping` result.

Comment: Okay, so if I delete `Include` and `ThenInclude`, still got translation error @SvyatoslavDanyliv

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242032/discussion-between-svyatoslav-danyliv-and-eugene-sukh).

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv what was the final answer?

Comment: @Sora. it is a little bit outdated question and I have already answered above. After conversation with OP, I have prepared query which is suitable for him. If you have some issues with EF Core, create new question.